# Remove a div if screen size is smaller than 640px

Tags: jquery

A client of mine has an auto-playing media player on his site and he doesn't want it to display at all on mobiles (Or screens smaller than 640px).

I can't just set it to `display:none` as it still autoplays. Is there a way to do it using jQuery?

The audio player is wrapped in a div with a class of `.audio`

Comment: If the media player is flash, I'm not sure it's possible (or its depends of the methods available by it). With html5, @dystroy made a correct answer I think :)

Comment: Do you want to consider redimensions?

Answer (score 3):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to hide it and then start it if only if it's visible :

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
      .audio {
         display:none;
      }
}

$( window ).load(function() {
    $('#yourplayer:visible').get(0).start();
});
```

This has two advantages :

- it separates the code from the size and presentation logic
- you probably have other size related content, they're hidden/tuned in the same place

Comment: As the OP said, he can't just set display: none; as it will autoplay.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 640) {
        $('div.audio').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('.audio').remove();`

Comment: This does not stop something for playing in every browser

Comment: @Asenar how can you explain ?

Comment: I didn't explain why, just had the same issue some times ago, but it's required to stop the thing to be played (either the html5 element or the flash if the player is not html)

Comment: @Asenar my code is removing the player from DOM than how will it play ?? If it is not present ???

Comment: maybe it's the flash support or something I don't know. it happens on Chrome and IE.

Comment: @Asenar if the element is removed it will not present.So no issue of playing

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider windows re dimensions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   changeElements();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        changeElements();
    });
});

function changeElements(){    
     if ($(window).width() <= 640) {
        $('#divId').hide();
        $('#divId').get(0).pause();
    }else{
        $('#divId').show();
        $('#divId').get(0).play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enquirejs.

```
enquire.register("max-width: 640px", function() {
  // Remove your player here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the div has no **id**

```
$(function() {
    if($('body').width() < 640) {
        $('div').removeClass("audio");
    }
})
```